# How to upgrade dpkg if already newest version? // apt-get upgrade broken by dpkg; Caused by LetsEncrypt Certbot backport

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, dependencies, letsencrypt

On Debian 9.4 Stretch

Accidently `updated && upgraded` to the `jessie-backports`, then changed the `sources.list` to the correct `stretch-backports`.

Can this kill my apt?

If not:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

gives

```
The following packages have been kept back:
[...] 116 not upgraded.
```

The reason for that seems to be `dpkg`:

```
sudo apt-get install -f util-linux
[Going down the dependency breaks]
sudo apt-get install -f perl-base
perl-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.17) but 1.16.17 is to be installed
            Breaks: texinfo (< 6.1.0.dfsg.1-8) but 4.13a.dfsg.1-10 is to be installed

sudo apt-get install -f dpkg
dpkg is already the newest version.
```

To install Certbot from `stretch-backports` we need to solve the `util-linux` dependency issue caused by dpkg, right?

Is this even possible?

Comment: removing `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main` and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't fix the upgrade dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /etc/issue
```

gave me `Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l`

So I replaced the old `wheezy` package configuration in my sources.list; changed them to `stretch`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Unfortunately, the packages seems to have been on wheezy and now upgraded through jessie to stretch.

Comment: Please change your post to reflect the steps you took to solve the issue.